# Executing long task on UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, binding

I am developing a simple custom control which should act as a menu system. It consists of 2 buttons : Back and Home and the menu items above.
The ControlTemplate looks like this :

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="FancyColorPickerTemplate">
        <menu:BusyDecorator x:Name="BusyDecorator"  Style="{StaticResource BusyDecoratorStyle}">
            <menu:BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="IsBusy" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CustomControls:Menu}}"/>
                </PriorityBinding>
            </menu:BusyDecorator.IsBusyIndicatorShowing>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.70*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.30*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Name="Part_ItemControl" 
                        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
                <Button  Grid.Row="1" Name="PART_BackButton"  FontSize="20" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Button  Grid.Row="1" Name="PART_HomeButton"  FontSize="20" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </menu:BusyDecorator>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

On the ItemsControl there's a ItemTemplateSelector to select the DataTemplate of the displayed elements (which can be a button or maybe a UserControl).
Example :

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ></Button>
          </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControlTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="10,0,10,0">
            <CustomControls:ColorPickerUserControl Width="200"   Height="200"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In the Codebehind, I check which element is clicked and load a submenu (by setting the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl) if needed :

```
 void Menu_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl itemsControl = GetTemplateChild("Part_ItemControl") as ItemsControl;
        object item = GetElementFromPoint(itemsControl, e.GetPosition(itemsControl));

        if (item != null && item is MenuItem2)
        {
            MenuItem2 mi = item as MenuItem2;
            if (mi.SubMenu != null)
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                 {
                     MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem2>(mi.SubMenu.Items);
                     IsBusy = false;
                 }));
                m_MenuStack.Push(mi.SubMenu);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!IsBusy)
                {
                    ExecuteAction(mi.Ac);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no item found");
    }
```

The MenuItems in the code above is binded to the ItemsSource property, which will reevaluate the ItemsControl and apply the corresponding DataTemplate based on the DataTemplateSelector.
The problem in my code is with the IsBusy property above which should display the BusyDecorator (see xaml) and the DataTemplate is a UserControl which take a long time to display. It doesn't work because I guess the UserControl is loading on the UI thread, as well as the IsBusy property triggers an action on the UI thread.

Am I following a wrong approach ? Is there any way to make this work ?

Comment: I would suggest to use .net 4.5 and then implement it with the Async/Await Feature

Comment: That would be a nice solution. Unfortunaly we only have framework 3.5 on our embedded system.

Comment: The you could go the long way (actually what Async/Await does) and put it in a seperate thread and implement a handler, which receives a notification when the thread for loading has finished

Comment: I've already tried using a separate thread but it doesn't work. The problem, I guess, is that the UserControl is constructed an the UI thread, and I don't know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set the busy flag and schedule the rest of the work on the UI thread after the rendering is complete for the busy set.

The magic part here is that the thread is scheduled using the priority `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render` which makes the task run at the same time as rendering.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click_1">LongTask</Button>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBusyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsBusy", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                IsBusy = false;
            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
        }
    }
}
```